# how to convert gps north and gps west to lat/long in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, gps, location

I got these values from server:

```
<gps_n>34.22.123</gps_n>
<gps_w>81.59.345</gps_w>
```

I would like to convert these values to latitude/longitude in Objective C. Would you please give me a guide to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula for both lat/long (n/w) is:

> Degrees+(minutes/60)+(seconds/3600)

From this page:

http://webmaster10.com/ldr/lat-long-conversion.html

Answer (score 1):

The example you have given, already are latitude/longitude coordinates. There are many such lat,lon formats, what you want are lat/long coordinates in **decimal degrees**, probably with a sign to denote N/S or E/W.

Use the formula above:  (`Degrees+(minutes/60)+(seconds/3600)`)
 and multiply latitude with -1 when S is given.
Multiply longitude by -1 when "W" is given.